# Is the converse of Sylvester's inertia law true?

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ symmetric matrices.

Assume the positive,negative,0 index of $A$ and $B$ are the same. (That is, they have the same inertia)

Then, are $A,B$ congruent?

What is a counterexample?

Comment: What do you mean by congruent?

Comment: $B=Q^tAQ$ where $Q$ is invertible

Comment: If two matrices are conjugate to a third, they are conjugate to each other.

Comment: Ok, so if they're congruent then you can change A into B by a series of elementary row operations. That should make obvious that your statement is true if A and B are diagonal. Maybe that can help with the general case.

Comment: @mtiano that's not what congruent means, unless you're talking about simultaneous row and corresponding column operations

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That is what I mean since any invertible matrix can be represented as a series of elementary row operations. $Q^T$ gives the corresponding column operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is true (over the real and complex numbers). If $A$ and $B$ have the same inertia, then they are both congruent to the same diagonal matrix of $1$s, $-1$s, and $0$s. By transitivity, they are congruent to each other.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the base field you are working with.

For a field like the reals or complex numbers, where every positive element is a square, the answer is yes. There are two changes of basis that make both into the Gram matrix with 1's, 0's and -1's on the diagonal according to index, and by transitivity both matrices are cogredient.

For an ordered field whose positive elements aren't all squares, I think the answer is no. These matrices have matching indices, but aren't cogredient over $\Bbb Q$:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$